# set tabular/align width within landscape multicols

Tags: tables, amsmath, multicol, width

```
\documentclass[10pt,landscape,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utopia,sfscaled]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.5pt}
\usepackage[top=0mm,bottom=1mm,left=1mm,right=1mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{microtype}

\let\bar\overline

\definecolor{myblue}{cmyk}{1,.72,0,.38}

\everymath\expandafter{\the\everymath \color{myblue}}
\everydisplay\expandafter{\the\everydisplay \color{myblue}}

\newcommand{\header}{
\begin{mdframed}[style=header]
\footnotesize
Math cheat sheet \\
Page~\thepage~of~3
\end{mdframed}
}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\section}{\@startsection{section}{1}{0mm}%
                            {.2ex}%
                            {.2ex}%x
                            {\sffamily\bfseries}}

\begin{document}
\small
\begin{multicols*}{4}
\header
\columnbreak
\subsection*{Ableitungen}
\begin{align*}
f(x)&=u(x)+v(x)&\rightarrow f^\prime(x)&=u^\prime(x)+v^\prime(x) \\
f(x)&=\lambda*u(x)&\rightarrow  f^\prime(x)&=\lambda*u^\prime(x) \\
f(x)&=u(x)*v(x)&\rightarrow f^\prime(x)&=u^\prime(x)*v(x)+u(x)*v^\prime(x) \\
f(x)&=u(v(x))&\rightarrow f^\prime(x)&=u^\prime(v(x))*v^\prime(x) \\
f(x)&=\frac{u(x)}{v(x)}&\rightarrow f^\prime(x)&=\frac{u^\prime(x)*v(x)+u(x)*v^\prime(x)}{[v(x)^2]}
\end{align*}
\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

1.Why does the tabular width go over the columnwidth of the whole page and how can I set it?

2.And also Texing it gives me this:

```
    ./cheatsheet.tex:107: Improper \halign inside $$'s.
    <recently read> \halign 

     l.107  \end{align*}
```

can someone pls help :) Thank you

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Which `tabular` do you mean? Your code doesn't include one. Note that `tabular` is a specific environment. Can you please edit your question (including its title), to be comprehensible?

Comment: You have an error in the last line by the way. The derivative should be `\frac{u' v - u v' }{ v^2 }`

Comment: Ah! sorry, my bad. In this case it is the \align

Comment: You have several options: Changing the font size could be one. In this case however just leaving out all the `\rightarrow` instructions results in fitting contents and remains easily legible.

Comment: Thank you! and do you know why I get that fault message?

Comment: Sorry, I have no clue. An empty `align*` environment results in the same error.

Comment: You can change the `align*` environment to `\begin{equation*}\begin{aligned}...\end{aligned}\end{equation*}`. It results in slightly different vertical spacing and you don't get an error.

Comment: I tried changing to tabular enviroment but it still didnt quiet fit in haha but using your code worked ! Thank you!

Comment: Btw. you could do something like this: `\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left( \frac{u}{v} \right) &= \frac{u'v - uv'}{v^2}` with every line. That is way smaller and contains every bit of important information. Did you read my second comment (I just want to make sure you don't get bad grades because you used a wrong quotient rule)?

Comment: Yes I did Thank you so much!:) I'm trying to make this 'cheat sheet' for our math course in uni. I volunteered but now I'm stuggling quite a bit haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `alignat*` and replacing your construct, as pointed by @David Carlisle with a simple `\everymath{color{myblue}}` makes the code compile (almost) normally. B.t.w. you'll obtain almost the same colour using `MidnightBlue` (one of the colours defined by the `svgnames` option of `xcolor`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,landscape,a4paper, svgnames, x11names]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utopia,sfscaled]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.5pt}
\usepackage[top=0mm,bottom=1mm,left=1mm,right=1mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{microtype}
\let\bar\overline
\definecolor{myblue}{cmyk}{1,.72,0,.38}

%\everymath\expandafter{\the\everymath \color{myblue}}
%\everydisplay\expandafter{\the\everydisplay \color{myblue}}

\everymath{\color{MidnightBlue}}
\newcommand{\header}{
\begin{mdframed}[style=header]
\footnotesize
Math cheat sheet \\
Page~\thepage~of~3
\end{mdframed}
}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\section}{\@startsection{section}{1}{0mm}%
                            {.2ex}%
                            {.2ex}%x
                            {\sffamily\bfseries}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\small
\begin{multicols*}{4}
\header
\columnbreak
\subsection*{Ableitungen}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
f(x)&=u(x)+v(x)&{}\rightarrow f'(x)&=u'(x)+v'(x) \\
f(x)&=\lambda*u(x)&{}\rightarrow f'(x)&=\lambda*u'(x) \\
f(x)&=u(x)*v(x)&{}\rightarrow f'(x)&=u'(x)*v(x)+u(x)*v'(x) \\
f(x)&=u(v(x))&{}\rightarrow f'(x)&=u'(v(x))*v'(x) \\
f(x)&=\frac{u(x)}{v(x)}&{}\rightarrow f'(x)&=\frac{u'(x)*v(x)+u(x)*v'(x)}{[v(x)^2]}
\end{alignat*}
\end{multicols*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for stealing my tick:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: — Borrowed, mylord! ;o)

Answer (score 2):

The error is due to

```
\everydisplay\expandafter{\the\everydisplay \color{myblue}}
```

which is not a supported construct.

The `\halign` primitive that underlies all LaTeX alignments has a special display-math behaviour if used as the first item in a `$$` display math, `\align` depends on that behaviour, but if you insert a colour special at the start of the math list, it is inserted before the `\halign` primitive even though the align expands to

```
 $$\halign....
```

Comment: Any possibility to set every display in `myblue` but still use `align`?

Comment: Why? All entries are already blue due to everymath @Skillmon

Comment: @DavidCarlisle whoopsie, missed that.

Comment: What would you suggest as an alternative to `\everydisplay=\expandafter{\the\everydisplay\color{red}` if a person wants all display-math material to be rendered in red?

Comment: @Mico there's some work going on to improve hook support generally but you could use the environment hooks provided by etoolbox to add it to \begin{equation} and other display envs.

Comment: Many thanks for providing this pointer.

Comment: Your answer turned out to be wonderfully helpful while I was updating [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/552109/5001) to get around complications caused by trying to use `\everydisplay`. Thanks again!