# Math mode does not recognize color

Tags: math-mode, color, unicode-math

I change color globally in math mode, but if I try to change the color locally only to one symbol or letter, it does'n have effect.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amssymb,verbatim,amsthm,amsmath,color}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\definecolor{navy}{rgb}{0.0, 0.0,0.5}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[slash-delimiter=frac,Color=navy]{Cambria Math}

\begin{document}
$$x^2-y^2=1$$
$$x^2-(\textcolor{red}{1})^2=1$$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Off-topic: (a) Don't load the `fontenc` package when using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. (b) Don't load both `xcolor` and `color`.

Comment: Adding to the comment by @Mico: you do not need `amssymb` if you load `unicode-math`, which will just overwrite everything in it.  You should not load `fontenc` together with Unicode fonts. You would not normally need to load `amsmath` with `unicode-math`, but you are also loading `amsthm`, so load ``amsmath` **before** `amsthm`.

Comment: Basically, `unicode-math` makes almost all legacy font packages redundant, although it’s written to be robust if you load many of them anyway.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

(I updated this answer significantly after learning that modifying `\everydisplay` can cause serious problems with various display math style environments.)

Setting the `Color=...` option while loading a math font appears to override anything that `\textcolor` is supposed to do.

Instead of setting a `Color` option at the `\setmathfont` stage, you may achieve your objective by (a) modifying the `\everymath` token list for inline math material and (b) providing an `\apptocmd` directive to set the default color for `\[ ... \]` material and, similarly, `\AtBeginEnvironment` directives for the `equation` and `equation*` environments. It turns out not be necessary to provide analogous commands for the display math environments of the `amsmath` package.

Observe that this approach does *not* work for `$$ ... $$` material. This is deliberate. For an in-depth discussion of why one should **not** use `$$` in a LaTeX document to initiate and terminate display math mode, please see the posting [Why is `\[ ... \]` preferable to `$$ ... $$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/5001).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % provides various displaymath environments

\usepackage{xcolor} % for '\definecolor', '\color', and '\textcolor'
\definecolor{navy}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.5}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[slash-delimiter=frac]{Cambria Math}

% Auto-color inline math material:
\everymath=\expandafter{\the\everymath\color{navy}} 
% Auto-color display math material:
\usepackage{etoolbox} % <-- required for XeLaTeX; optional for LuaLaTeX
\apptocmd{\[}{\color{navy}}{}{}
\AtBeginEnvironment{equation}{\color{navy}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{equation*}{\color{navy}}


\begin{document}
% First, some inline math material.
\(0+\textcolor{red}{1}=1\), 
\begin{math}1+1=\textcolor{red}{2}\end{math}, 
$\textcolor{red}{2}+1=3$.
%% Second, various forms of display math material.
\[
x^2-(\textcolor{red}{1})^2=1
\]
\begin{equation*}
x^2-(\textcolor{red}{1})^2=1
\end{equation*}
\begin{gather}
x^2-y^2=1\\
x^2-(\textcolor{red}{1})^2=1
\end{gather}
\begin{align*}
x^2-y^2&=1\\
x^2-(\textcolor{red}{1})^2&=1
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank's for you answer, I only have a problem, align environment give an error "improper \halign inside $$'s"

Comment: @OrEsc - Please see the update I've applied ot my answer.

Answer (score 8):

One way to accomplish this is to insert the symbol as text:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,verbatim}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\pagestyle{empty} % Suppress page numbers in this MWE.

\setmainfont{STIX Two Text}
\setmathfont[slash-delimiter=frac,Color=Navy]{STIX Two Math}

\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
x^2-y^2=1 \\
x^2-( \textnormal{\textcolor{Red}{1}} )^2=1
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

[image: Math color sample]

A more versatile approach, capable of supporting arbitrary math arguments, is to define a red math version, and write a `\redsymbol` command for it, similar to `\boldsymbol` from `amsbsy.sty`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,verbatim}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\pagestyle{empty} % Suppress page numbers in this MWE.

\setmainfont{STIX Two Text}
\setmathfont[Color=Navy]{STIX Two Math}
\setmathfont[version=red,Color=Red]{STIX Two Math}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\redmath}{\mathversion{red}}
\newcommand{\redsymbol}[1]{% Based on \boldsymbol from amsbsy.sty
  \math@atom{#1}{%
    \mathchoice%
      {\hbox{\redmath$\displaystyle#1$}}%
      {\hbox{\redmath$\textstyle#1$}}%
      {\hbox{\redmath$\scriptstyle#1$}}%
      {\hbox{\redmath$\scriptscriptstyle#1$}}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
x^2-y^2=1 \\
x^2-(\redsymbol{\phi_i})^2=1
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

[image: Color test sample]

Answer (score 5):

I'm afraid that the Color option to the font overrides any color specification, because it's applied later.

You can define a noncolored font for a different math version and specify it. I added an optional argument to help in case the symbol is not an ordinary one.

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\definecolor{navy}{rgb}{0.0, 0.0,0.5}
\setmathfont[slash-delimiter=frac,Color=navy]{Cambria Math}
\setmathfont[version=black,slash-delimiter=frac]{Cambria Math}
\setmathfont[version=bold]{XITS Math}

\newcommand{\cm}[3][\mathord]{%
  #1{\text{\mathversion{black}\textcolor{#2}{$#3$}}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
x^2-(1)^2=1 \\
x^2-(\cm{red}{1})^2=1 \\
x^2\cm[\mathbin]{red}{-}(1)^2=1\\
\sum_{i=1}^n x_{\cm{red}{i}} \\
\cm[\mathop]{red}{\sum}_{i=1}^n x_{\cm{red}{i}}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]